# Possibly undefined behaviour C++14/17

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14

I have a string class that triggers an access violation in Visual Studio 2019, using v141 toolchain. In production the crash was first seen after changing compiler language support to C++17, however I also see it happening when using C++14. From my perspective the code looks sane, but I'd like to have a second opinion. Is there any undefined behavior in the code below?

```
class string
{
public:
    string();
    ~string();

    string(const string& s);
    string& operator=(const string& s);

    string(const          char* sString, int nCount = -1);

    operator const char* () const { return m_lpsData; }

protected:
    char* m_lpsData;
};

string::string()
    : m_lpsData(0)
{
}

string::~string()
{
}

string::string(const string& s)
    : m_lpsData(0)
{
}

string& string::operator=(const string& s)
{
    return *this;
}

string::string(const char* sString, int nCount)
    : m_lpsData(0)
{ }

struct Foo
{
    Foo(const char* c)
        : m_c(c) 
    {}

    operator const string() const
    {
        return m_c;
    }

    const char* m_c;
};

void set(const string s) { }

int main()
{
    set(static_cast<const string>(Foo("test")));
}
```

Crash does not happen if I remove the `static_cast`, change the conversion operator in `Foo` to `operator string() const` or remove the dtor from string.

Compiler version (I do not see problems with g++ 12.1 or clang 14.0.4):

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30146 for x86
```

Command line:

```
cl /JMC /permissive- /ifcOutput "Debug\" /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"Debug\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /FC /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\Project1.pch" /diagnostics:column main.cpp
```

Comment: Converting string literal to `char*` is undefined behavior. https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/STR30-C.+Do+not+attempt+to+modify+string+literals

Comment: Right, but there is no such conversion. I need the `char *` member, so I get the access violation, but I don't assign other than 0 to it.

Comment: `string& string::operator=(const string& s)` -- Writing assignment operators and copy constructors that don't actually do those things are a source of bugs to happen, and those bugs are some of the toughest to track down.  Don't write stubbed out versions of these functions -- actually make the copy do what it's supposed to do, and that is to make a copy (you failed to copy the members in the `string` class).

Comment: Apart from the broken logic (e.g. string constructors doing nothing) the example looks legal. However it is very easy to do a small change and have UB.

Comment: Can't reproduce on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/abxdzqrTo) (although I had to remove some of the compiler flags). Also, looks valid to me. Does **exactly** this example crash? Also, what does the debugger tell you (exact location)?

Comment: I removed the contents of the functions to get to a minimum example.

Comment: The crash happens in `string::string(const char* , int )`. The constructor receives an invalid this pointer. In the disassembly it seems that the location (temporary in `main`s stack) is not correctly initialized for whatever reason. My impression is that its a bug in msvc but I wanted to make sure there's no ub before.